# What configuration do I need to run TestCafe in WebStorm

Tags: testing, configuration, automated-tests, webstorm, testcafe

I would like to run/debug TestCafe tests using WebStorm. Does anyone have 
a suggested configuration I need to do this?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nHP8.png]

Answer (score 4):

WebStorm doesn't provide any special support for TestCafe (if you miss it, please vote for [WEB-30315](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-30315)); but you can use [VS Code instructions](http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/recipes/debug-in-visual-studio-code.html) to run/debug in WebStorm. Namely, you need [Node.js](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2018.2/run-debug-configuration-node-js.html) Run configuration like the following:

[image]

where **JavaScript file:** is set to a path to your locally installed testcafe module, e.g. `node_modules\testcafe\bin\testcafe.js`, and **Application parameters:** are testcafe cli args, like `chrome myTestFile.js`